# Roboelectric issues with new gradle and android sdk versions

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

I used to be able to use roboelectric with gradle just fine until recently. I keep getting an error `Error:(6, 17) error: package org.junit does not exist`. I'm not quite sure and have dug into this quite a bit.

Below is my project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Below is my app build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...

    sourceSets {
        androidTest.setRoot('src/test')
    }
}


dependencies {
    ...

    // Testing
    compile project(':core')
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
    testCompile 'org.easytesting:fest:1.0.16'
    testCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.8'
}
```

my core project build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
}
```

I have read the below regarding this and nothing here has worked for me:

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/all-in-together-android-studio-gradle-and-robolectric/ - the android studio plugin that is to be used crashes on newer android studio versions.

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/triumph-android-studio-1-2-sneaks-in-full-testing-support/ - this simply doesn't solve the problem. It cannot find org.junit.

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/why-cant-my-simplest-one-line-build-gradle-compile-tests-with-junit-jar/1868

Can anybody point me in the right direction for this? Why is it not able to detect `org.junit` from the `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the build variant test artifact to `Unit Tests`.

[image]

I no longer needed the "core" project, so I deleted it. My build.gradle for my app looks like this:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        androidTest.setRoot('src/test')
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...

    // Testing
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.easytesting:fest:1.0.16'
    testCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.8'
    testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc2') {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

last day i am also facing the problem.Atlast i got the solution.

The error is due to you created the java folder for your test class as java folder which appear **blue color** in android studio.Actually you need it in **green color**

For testing you just need to create folder with java name,everything else will do by android studio itself.

for removing java folder dependency you can remove

```
  sourceSets {
    androidTest.setRoot('src/test')
}
```

code from the build.gradle

then everything will work fine

Comment: That makes no sense. The above configuration is straight from documentation. It's supposed to be written that way.

Comment: I already had it working. My answer above is the accepted answer as per the documentation for Roboelectric. Basically you have to set the Unit Testing framework so that it includes JUnit.

Comment: Also, that `sourceSets` is a very important line. It tells it how to organize the code for unit tests. I'm surprised your gradle project is configured properly and all unit tests are working... Something else seems at issue here.

Comment: may i know what is your test java file color

Comment: The file and package below are green.

Comment: ok then no problem,also we dont need to tell the android studio to what is our sourceset folder path ,studio will do it its own way using some algorithm